# Programmatically focus an element's first eligable child?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an accordion-like component, and when the container for a given step is opened, I want the first form element inside to receive focus.

I know that I can programmatically set focus using a ref, but that requires implementation on the individual form elements which is a bit cumbersome in my context.

ie. here's a solution that does what I want:

```
const Box = ({ isVisible, children }) => {
  return (
    <div className={isVisible ? "box visible" : "box"}>
      {isVisible && children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Input = ({ autoFocus }) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref);
    if (ref.current && autoFocus) {
      ref.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return <input ref={ref} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const { current } = ref;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(current);
    if (current) {
      current.focus();
      console.log("focus", current);
    }
  }, [current]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((v, i) => (
        <button onClick={() => setActive(v)} key={"button" + v}>
          {v}
        </button>
      ))}
      {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((v, i) => (
        <Box isVisible={v === active} key={"box" + v}>
          <Input autoFocus />
          <Input />
          {v}
        </Box>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-glade-z7j60?file=/src/App.js:84-1211)

The problem I have with this solution is that I have to manually implement that `autoFocus` functionality on my `Input`, and you can imagine if I also have `Dropdown`, `DateSelector` etc it's a bit cumbersome.

What I'd like to do instead is have my `Box` component do something like this:

```
const Box = ({ isVisible, children }) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isVisible && ref.current) {
      ref.current.focusChildren();
    }
  }, [isVisible]);
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className={isVisible ? "box visible" : "box"}>
      {isVisible && children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

where we can let the HTML engine decide which the next focusable element is, and focus on that.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can write a method to find the first focusable element within your visible box and then set the focus.

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-meadow-md9kz?file=/src/App.js)

```
const findFirstFocusableElement = container => {
  return Array.from(container.getElementsByTagName("*")).find(isFocusable);
};

const isFocusable = item => { 
  if (item.tabIndex < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  switch (item.tagName) {
    case "A":
      return !!item.href;
    case "INPUT":
      return item.type !== "hidden" && !item.disabled;
    case "SELECT":
    case "TEXTAREA":
    case "BUTTON":
      return !item.disabled;
    default:
      return false;
  }
};
```

---

```
const Box = ({ isVisible, children }) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isVisible && ref.current) {
      const firstFocusableInput = findFirstFocusableElement(ref.current);
      firstFocusableInput && firstFocusableInput.focus();
    }
  }, [isVisible, children]);
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className={isVisible ? "box visible" : "box"}>
      {isVisible && children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Nice soultion, thanks. I wonder if there is a standard library/method for that `isFocusable`